# Fixing the low performance issue in Flutter web

Tags: flutter

Create a Flutter Web project, the performance issues are visible even if it's a completely blank app
Open the web page in Firefox
Use 4k screen, or if you don't have one, simulate it using Firefox Dev Tools
See FPS is drastically lower, than with lower resolutions
This happens only when using the CanvasKit renderer. In comparison, Chrome is able to render the same page at constant 75 FPS.

Expected results
The frame rate shouldn't degenerate with higher resolutions, when the app doesn't even need to draw anything.

Actual results
The frame rate is significantly lower, than with lower resolutions. (for 4k it's around 20FPS and a lot of input lag)

Answer (score 0):

For rendering websites, Flutter uses two renderers: HTML and canvaskit.

What's the difference between them?
The canvaskit renderer adds a 1.5MB overhead to your site but resolves performance issues and widget bugs.

By default, canvaskit is used for desktop and HTML for mobile.

If you only experience performance issues on desktop, the problem might lie in the site implementation or Flutter's own limitations (personally, I haven't encountered performance issues).

If widgets aren't displayed correctly on mobile or performance is poor, it's due to rendering with HTML.

What's the temporary solution?
To run or build, use the option:

```
--web-renderer
```

like this:

```
flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer canvaskit
flutter build web --web-renderer canvaskit
```

What's the permanent solution?
In the project files, go to web > index.html
Scroll down to the bottom and change this section:

```
onEntrypointLoaded: function(engineInitializer) {
  engineInitializer.initializeEngine().then(function(appRunner) {
    appRunner.runApp(); 
  });
}
```

to this:

```
onEntrypointLoaded: function(engineInitializer) {
  let config = {
    renderer: "canvaskit",
  };
  engineInitializer.initializeEngine(config).then(function(appRunner) {
    appRunner.runApp(); 
  });
}
```

Hope you enjoy it ⚡️